# Получение элемента из другого fxml и с методами другого котроллера

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

Приложение имеет TabPane, имеем кнопку которая в TabPabe добавляет ещё один Tab, но этот Tab вместе с контентом **не создаётся** в контроллере основного класса main, а берётся из другого, второго fxml, с подключенным  другим котроллером, то есть добавленный Tab будет взаимодействовать с полями и методами из второго котроллера. Подскажите как такое соорудить.

Или даже другой вариант, не обязательно добавлять из другого приложения готовый Tab, а добавить готовый AnchorPane который будет находиться в Tab который создам в основном котроллере.

Comment: Между контроллерами есть какая либо связь?

Comment: находятся в одном проекте, просто Мне бы хотелось увидеть стандартный код, или не стандартный, для таких ситуаций, то есть к примеру создаём экземпляр класса второго контроллера, в основной контроллер через FXMLLoader загружаем второй fxml файл. но мозговался, не получилось.